# How to convert a date time (in a specific timezone) to epoch seconds

Tags: perl, date, time, seconds

I have a datetime object in a specific timezone namely 'Asia/Tokyo'.
I am getting this datetime using `$dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'Asia/Tokyo');`
The output of this is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD'P'HH:mm:ss` (`P` is delimiter)

Please help with perl script to convert this to datetime to epoch seconds.

Comment: Does `$dt->epoch` not work for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime->now(time_zone => 'Asia/Tokyo')->epoch
```

Of course, you will get the same result no matter which time zone you specify if you use `now`, and it's going to be the same as the output of [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html).

---

These all refer to the same time (now):

```
>perl -MDateTime -E"say time"
1313046840

>perl -MDateTime -E"say DateTime->now(time_zone => 'Asia/Tokyo')->epoch"
1313046840

>perl -MDateTime -E"say DateTime->now(time_zone => 'America/New_York')->epoch"
1313046840
```

These refer to different times:

```
>perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -E"say DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%F %T', time_zone => 'Asia/Tokyo')->parse_datetime('2011-08-11 13:00:00')->epoch"
1313035200

>perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -E"say DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%F %T', time_zone => 'America/New_York')->parse_datetime('2011-08-11 13:00:00')->epoch"
1313082000
```